# Scrum user stories for rebuilding an existing web site

Tags: jira, scrum, user-stories, jira-agile, kanban

I am having second thoughts about using Scrum for rebuilding an existing site from scratch while maintaining some of the features from the previous site. While we're still in the "re-discovery" phase of the project, I am wondering if could I include other user roles such as content strategist (for auditing the content), site builder, etc? I am aware scrum keeps end-users in mind for stories, however, can I add other user roles for project planning and estimation purposes?

Namely, I am using JIRA scrum board and have created epics based on the phases (i.e. Google Analytics, Content Audit Phase). What would be the user roles in these cases? We're still gathering the requirements. Should I just go create tasks instead and run the sprints based on those tasks? Or should I use kanban?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're first sentence leads me to believe you are encountering some mental friction when trying to fit your project within the guidance provided by Scrum.

I'd also like to state that "types of people" who are going to use your web application are typically called *personas* in by agile teams. So using the example from above...

> "As an SEO specialist... "

The SEO specialist would be a persona. You can have as many personas as you'd like on an agile project. Keep it reasonable so you don't get bogged down in details that aren't useful, but there is no limit.

When it comes to roles *on the project team*, that is where the guidance from Scrum starts to feel like a constraint. Scrum says you have an SM, PO, and Team members. What is a Content Strategist do on a Scrum team? They can be a Team Member and do work (participate in estimation, delivery, planning).

The work that they do would be done within the sprint, just like anyone else, on the "user story" that they were working on.

Scrum (as prescribed) should be fairly strict. And this strictness is usually what causes people to look to other methodologies like Kanban or the team drops the strictness of Scrum and they are no longer *doing Scrum*.

Kanban (or should I say the Kanban Method) as described by David Anderson and LeanKanban University are not a straight across replacement from Scrum. Virtual kanban systems are a work management technique that is used by the Kanban Method. Virtual kanban systems can be used to augment the way an agile team uses their board and manages their work to allow them to expand beyond the constraints of Scrum while still being disciplined. Using virtual kanban systems is ***not a get out of jail free card*** that lets you become undisciplined.

A virtual kanban system, done right, will describe the process that **you** need for **your** project, and allow it to evolve over time to continually improve and fit the needs of the team. This freedom is where virtual kanban systems are a significant improvement over the guidance provided by Scrum. They allow you to take the training wheels off.

Virtual kanban systems allow you to:

- describe your workflow as it is
- alter your workflow as needed
- not change or worry about a job title - focus on the work, not the role
- put the kinds of work that are required (work items) through the system without worrying if they are *user stories* or *post-delivery work* or *pre-development work*
- focus on problems like blocked or late items
- allow for constantly evolving understanding of the priorities of the project and act on that information
- understand how long it takes for work to move through the kanban system
- reduce overburdening with WIP limits, allowing the team to focus on getting work finished before starting on new work
- build a better and constantly improving process
- provide the same levels of transparency and stakeholder involvement as any other agile methodology

Before embarking on the decision to "switch" to Kanban, I would encourage you to read the new book by Mike Burrows - "Kanban from the Inside" ([Amazon link](http://www.amazon.ca/Kanban-Inside-Mike-Burrows/dp/0985305193))  and develop a further understanding of how the Kanban Method can and should be implemented by your organization.

If you had a question about Jira (which I don't think you did), I'm sorry I don't have an answer for that part of your question.

Comment: This is very helpful. I will still stay with scrum. Scrum may not suitable for internal team organization (i.e. to do list for each sprint, would require a separate list, no?) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the roles in user stories are end-users as you mention. However, end-users do not just have to be the customers for the website. Other potential users might be the people who need to do site updates, the people who need to analyse the site analytics, etc.

For example you might have:

"As an SEO specialist I want the website to capture analytic information so that I can analyse the site use"

What you don't usually do is have roles relating to the actual development work. The reason for this is that the user stories are meant to deliver value to the stakeholders for the work. This helps the agile process by measuring progress in terms of business value rather than technical work completed.

Ideally the content audit would be a continual process throughout development. In agile terms we try to get work to a state of 'done' in each sprint. If the content audit is taking place at the end of the project then stories will only be partially done up until that audit takes place. This runs the risk of masking the true progress of the project. Think of each sprint as a mini-project, including all that is necessary to get to a potentially releasable website.

The choice between Scrum and Kanban is not trivial and depends on many factors. You might want to take a look at other questions on stack exchange that have been asked on this topic.